# Python features and the labels

Tags: python, pandas

```
DATA_PATH = 'data/iris_dataset.csv'
data = pd.read_csv("data/iris_dataset.csv")
```

How to separate the features and the labels from data. The labels are the column 'class'.
Assign a pd.DataFrame with the features to 'X'.
Assign a pd.Series with the labels to 'labels'.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code , to split features and labels from your dataset.

X= data.iloc[:,:-1]
labels= data.pop('labels')

[Input][image: Input data]

[Output]
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVoSY.jpg)[image: Output data]